# Firebase - snapshot based on ids

Tags: firebase, react-native, firebase-realtime-database

I've been looking everywhere for the logic to build a specific request, but I don't completely get the firebase philosophy. This is my data structure:

```
`users:{
  u1_id:{...}
  u2_id:{...}
  ...
},
 contacts:{
  u1_id:{
   contact1_id,
   contact2_id,
   ...
  }
}`
```

My first option would be a request that gets the data regarding the user id, the second one (the actual one) is to store the data I need from the contacts when they're added but I would need to run a big update for each contacts of each user and that doesn't seem to be the right solution. (I've check questions, firebase doc and videos)

The closest solution I found is this (from their youtube):

```
 function getUserContacts(key, cb){
  const rootRef = firebase.database().ref()
  const contactsRef = rootRef.child('contacts')
  const usersRef = rootRef.child('users')

  contactsRef.child(key).on('child_added', snap => {
    let userRef = usersRef.child(snap.key)
    userRef.once('value', cb)
  })

}
```

but it gives the users 1 by 1 and not an object with all my users

Edit: my temporary solution ->

```
firebase.database().ref('users')
    .on('value', snaps => {
      firebase.database().ref(`contacts/${currentUser.uid}`)
      .on('value', snapshot => {
        let userContacts = []
        snapshot.forEach(snapc => {
          snaps.forEach(snapu => {
            let duser = snapu
            if(snapc.key == snapu.key)
            {
              userContacts.push(snapu.val())
            }
          })
        })
        dispatch({
          type: CONTACTS_FETCH, 
          payload: userContacts
        })
      })
    })
```

Comment: This is a pretty vague question and to me at least, unclear what you are asking. You first want to get the data regarding the user id. What does that mean? Do you want to get the data from the users/user_id_x node? The second items says *a big update*. What is that, and what are you updating that's big?

Comment: Thank for your answer. The contacts tree only stores the id of users that have been added to a user's contact list. What I want is to get the details of these users only to show them in the contact list. The update problem is in the case where I store the data and not the id for each contact, if a user change is nickname for example I would have to update all occurences for each user that have this contact, I hope it's getting clear.

Comment: It's still unclear. Do you want to populate a list with contact information. In other words, read in the contact id's, iterate over the list and load each contact?

Comment: Exactly, but I'm stuck with firebase functions. I can get the contact id's, but I don't know how to get the details for each one in the same function.

Comment: As I had mentioned in the above comment; read I the id's... perhaps into an array and immediately after, iterate over the array and load the individual contact info. Use .value to read in the list of contact id's at once. You could also add the user id's a child of each contact that belongs to them and do a query for those.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The question is still a bit unclear but let me present three options:

If we want to populate a list with user_1's contacts, we read in the users contacts node by value. In this case, user_1 has two contacts; user_id2 and user_id3

```
contacts
   user_1
     user_id2: true
     user_id3: true
```

Value reads in the parent node (user_1) with all of the child data as well. Because we have the entire node of data (a snapshot) we can iterate over the child values of user_1 to obtain each user_idx (which is the key of each child node). As you iterate over the children, each will present a key, to which you can then read in that specific user node.

A second option is to change the structure.

```
contacts
   user_2
     name: "John"
     rank: "Captain"
     contact_of: "user_1"
   user_3
     name: "William"
     rank: "Second Officer"
     contact_of: "user_1"
```

with this structure, if user 1 wants to load their contacts, a simple query on the contacts node where contact_of = "user_1". That would load each contact and all of their data.

This second example works when a user has specific contacts that are not shared.

If multiple users can have multiple contacts, here's another option.

```
contacts
   user_2
     name: "Jean Luc"
     rank: "Captain"
     contact_of
        user_1: true
        user_2: true
   user_3
     name: "William"
     rank: "Second Officer"
     contact_of:
        user_1: true
        user_2: true
```

in this case, perform a [deep query](https://firebase.googleblog.com/2015/09/introducing-multi-location-updates-and_86.html) on the contacts node where contact_of/user_1 = true, which will present user_2 and user_3/

Comment: It's like the 3rd option: they're multiple users and they can have multiple contacts, a contact can be any of the other users. I've already read the deep query but it wasn't really clear to me. My problem was to have the latest informations about the contacts list of a user, which is the case now.

Comment: @Sai A standard query allows a query one level deep. In the third example, a query could be done on user_x/name or user_x/rank node. A deep query allows a query one level deeper, so a query could be done on user_x/contact_of. So a query like user_x/contact_of/user_1: true is possible. Deep queries are powerful and give access to data that would normally have to denormalized to get to. You could attach an observer to the contact node and if any contacts are updated, your app would be notified with the latest information. If my answer helps, please accept it so it can help others.